# want to extract html and height & width of div

Tags: jquery

my code is here which is not returning the result i want

```
var content = "<div id='content_dv'>";
         content += "<table border='1' style='height:auto;width:auto;'>";
         content += "<tr>";
         content += "<td>";
         content += "This is row 1";
         content += "</td>";
         content += "</tr>";
         content += "<tr>";
         content += "<td>";
         content += "This is row 2";
         content += "</td>";
         content += "</tr>";
         content += "<tr>";
         content += "<td>";
         content += "This is row 3";
         content += "</td>";
         content += "</tr>";
         content += "</table>";
         content += "</div>";

         alert($(content).find('#content_dv').html());
         alert("height "+$(content).find('#content_dv').height());
         alert("width " + $(content).find('#content_dv').width());
```

my content variable has some html and i want to show the data with in div id called "content_dv" and also i need to determine the height & width of the div and height & width of inner html of div.

so please help me why my code is not working. what wrong in my code. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is here the content must be appended/put to the DOM. Here how it works for me

```
var content = "<div id='content_dv'>";
     content += "<table border='1' style='height:auto;width:auto;'>";
     content += "<tr>";
     content += "<td>";
     content += "This is row 1";
     content += "</td>";
     content += "</tr>";
     content += "<tr>";
     content += "<td>";
     content += "This is row 2";
     content += "</td>";
     content += "</tr>";
     content += "<tr>";
     content += "<td>";
     content += "This is row 3";
     content += "</td>";
     content += "</tr>";
     content += "</table>";
     content += "</div>";

     $("body").append(content);

     alert($('#content_dv').html());
```

Comment: without appending things into body can't it work? i dont want to append into body. i got a code which i used and that works well. sp here i am giving the code.  jQuery.ajax({type: "POST",url: "Login_LightFace.aspx/GetHtml",data: {},
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
sHtml = data.d;
modal.load(jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm').html());},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus);  }});

Comment: You are using here the .load() Method, which loads[replaces the content] data in to the html element it called on. In my example this was just a simple example. You are free to put how you are going to put the new structure in the DOM.  See this for more informaton on [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `.find('#content_dv')` from your code.
What you're trying to do is to find an element with id `content_dv` *inside* an element with id `content_dv` ;)

PS
Your height and width will be equal to 0, for you've not yet injected your new element into the existing page markup.

Comment: without appending things into body can't it work? i dont want to append into body. i got a code which i used and that works well. sp here i am giving the code.  jQuery.ajax({type: "POST",url: "Login_LightFace.aspx/GetHtml",data: {},
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
sHtml = data.d;
modal.load(jQuery(sHtml).find('#frm').html());},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus);  }});

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Width and height are not absolute but related to the page element in which they are, and to the style applied to both them and - potentially - their parent so there are no witdh and height in abstract terms.